# Access Easy Movie Texture's file path

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm making a VR application for iOS/Android.
I just bought Easy Movie Texture, using latest Unity version.

I can play one of the video. But I don't know how to play multiple videos.
For example, how do I make a cardboard tap trigger to change a movie?

I’m using the Sphere Example.
I created a gameobject, inside it’s update() function has a if(Carboard.SDK.Triggered) that I want to change the target parameter in sphere (Media Player Control Script). (Change the video)

How do I access this object? Where Exactly that object is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `mediaPlayerCtrl.Load(movieName)` changes the movie. The movie must be in `StreamingAssets` for this to work properly (SD card is possible on Android, but requires more effort).

As you have issues with locating your `MediaPlayerCtrl` instance, here's an easy solution. Add this script to an example from Easy Movie Texture and use the `ChangeMovie` method.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class EMTChangeFile : MonoBehaviour
{

    // drag an instance of Media Player Ctrl or leave empty for autodetection
    public MediaPlayerCtrl mediaPlayerCtrl;

    void Awake ()
    {
        if (mediaPlayerCtrl == null)
        {
            mediaPlayerCtrl = FindObjectOfType<MediaPlayerCtrl>();
            if (mediaPlayerCtrl == null)
                throw new UnityException("No Media Player Ctrl object in scene");
        }
    }

    public void ChangeMovie(string movieName, bool autoplay = true)
    {
        mediaPlayerCtrl.Stop();
        mediaPlayerCtrl.Load(movieName);
        if(autoplay)
            mediaPlayerCtrl.Play();
        else
            mediaPlayerCtrl.Stop();
    }

}
```